# Does Dapper support an unknown number of result sets?

Tags: c#, ado.net, dapper

### Update:

As Marc noted below, my fundamental question is: What happens when Read() gets called more times than there are record sets when using QueryMultiple()?

---

I'm working on converting an existing DB call from using SqlDataReader to Dapper.

Having problems with it though. I call a sproc, which conditionally can call 1-4 more sprocs. So I an potentially have many results sets.
To simplify my explanation, lets assume I only have 1-2 result set(s). If the first sproc isn't called, but the second sproc IS called then my first Read() call eats up the first and only result set. Then I have a bunch of useless TeamItem objects that were supposed to be ProjectItem objects. Then of course it blows up on the second call to Read() because there isn't another result set.

Am I missing something about Dapper, or is this an extreme case that Dapper just won't be able to support feasibly?

```
if (_searchParams.WillSearchTeams)
{
    var teams = multi.Read<TeamItem>().ToList();
}
var projects = multi.Read<ProjectItem>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're already using QueryMultiple; it sounds like the fundamental question here is what happens when you call Read more times than there are grids. I suppose it could return an empty sequence, but I *suspect* some kind of TryRead would be preferable. No, it doesn't have tht currently - but it could in theory.

Comment: Yep I'm using QueryMultiple. It works fine when there ARE both result sets. Oh well I guess. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user well, what would you like it to do differently?

Comment: @MarcGravell has there been any momentum on a TryRead method(or return an empty sequence)?  I've never had the need before now, but I am working on a project where there *could* be multiple result sets and I am would love to avoid doing a `try {} catch{}` on each `Read()`.

Comment: @Gimbl there is now a property that indicates whether the multi-reader is fully consumed; is that what you want? `IsConsumed`

Comment: @Marc can you please suggest the way to implement TryRead.
as I am fetching 3 results from same query which can be in any random sequence depending on the parameters passed.

Comment: @RAJESHJAIN `TryRead` would be equivalent to checking the `IsConsumed` property on `GridReader` that didn't exist when this answer was added, but does now.

Comment: Marc issue that @RAJESHJAIN and I are working on is little different, I have posted same @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842343/dapper-fetch-any-pre-defined-type . We have pre-defined types and the return is IEnumerable of one of these types, based on input parameter and here GridReader as posted in the question is of little help. Though I am able to do it by using a long and convoluted method, where IDictionary typecasting and property reflection is used, I am not sure if there's a simpler way possible